# Upload multiple images with Laravel Framework

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a simple project which will allow the uploading of more than image dynamically
I have created the view which allows adding more than one image using jquery plugin and it doing just fine as i can see all the attachments on the web page.
The problem is that when i click the submit button and try to die and dump, thus dd($photos); and $photos being an array of the photos in the html name attribute of the input field,the datatype is array but it contains only one image while at the html i uploaded three images.

I have added my code snippets below

```
<div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="input-group control-group increment" >
                                        <input type="text" name="photos[]" class="form-control">
                                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Add region photo</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clone hide">
                                        <div class="control-group input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
                                            <input type="text" name="photos[]" class="form-control">
                                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove photo</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </div>
```

and also the jquery codes below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".btn-success").click(function(){
            var html = $(".clone").html();
            $(".increment").after(html);
        });

        $("body").on("click",".btn-danger",function(){
            $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
        });

    });

</script>
```

Can anyone help me with this, I am stack today is the second day

Thanks alot

Alex

Comment: include your code for uploading image please

Comment: $images=Input::file('photos');
            foreach($images as $image){
                $photo = new Photo();
                $id = Hotel::max('id');//return max id
                $filename=time()."-".Input::get('hotel_Name')."-".$image->getClientOriginalName();//get original file name and append to timestamp
                $path=public_path('img/hotel_images/'.$filename);
                Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(468,249)->save($path);
                $photo->image='img/hotel_images/'.$filename;
                $photo->save();
            }

Comment: The issue is when i dd($images) i expected to see an array with three images i upload but instead i see only one image

Comment: see result below

Comment: array:1 [▼
  0 => UploadedFile {#230 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "Hydrangeas.jpg"
    path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
    filename: "phpE6A2.tmp"
    basename: "phpE6A2.tmp"
    pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpE6A2.tmp"
    extension: "tmp"
    realPath: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpE6A2.tmp"
    aTime: 2018-04-06 07:45:01
    mTime: 2018-04-06 07:45:01
    cTime: 2018-04-06 07:45:01
    inode: 0
    size: 595284
    perms: 0100666
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    linkTarget: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpE6A2.tmp"
  }
]

Comment: the issue here i see the ones that are appended using jquery they are the ones not added in the array. Thus,only the default or first input tag is taken

Answer (score 0):

you can upload images like upload image and display preview to the user, in this approach user can also remove the selected image, on submit button you can convert base10 encoded image from preview then convert it to blob .here I[image] attache screenshot of my work. ask me for code if you need